# Do we need a separate Kubernetes cluster for HiveMQ?

Tags: azure-aks, hivemq

we run a AKS Cluster with about 35 Microservices and now need a HiveMQ.

We are unsure on how to proceed. We could just deploy a HiveMQ on our AKS cluster over helm as we did on the dev cluster.

But we are unsure if this is a good idea. Our concerns are, that the scaling of the services and the HiveMQ are not independent if we do so.

But of course to setup a hole ci/cd process for a AKS cluster for each stage and market comes with some work and costs.

We have around 20 Million end devices using our backend and scaling is a big issue. But I found nothing that explicitly says that we need a different Cluster to justify the planning of the work.

What is your opinion?

Thanks!
Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision is based on your resources, if you have a big cluster composed of reliable multiple nodes with reliable CPU/MEM do it on the same cluster but in a dedicated namespace.

Having it to another cluster will be the same, you will just have other nodes, are they more reliable than the one from the first cluster? DTS, but it will not be a bad idea, mainly if you deploy the cluster on another AKS region, one could say that this will be more "safe"

So it is absolutely up to you, personally if my first cluster is well managed and have a good support, I would have deployed it there.